# Spring SOAP WS working locally, but not on tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, soap

I'm trying to create a SOAP web-service, following the spring tutorial :
https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

It works like a charm locally ( ran using mvn spring-boot:run or directly into Eclipse ). Then, I packaged it into a war, and deployed it on a fresh tomcat 7 installation... and I can't fetch my service, getting 404 errors.

I use Java 8 and tomcat 7

Here's my classes
**Endpoint**

```
@Endpoint
public class ZepraEndPoint {

private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://fr/toto/urps/ws/zepra/WSgenerate";

@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "sendDocumentToZepraRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public SendDocumentToZepraResponse SendDocumentToZepraResponse(@RequestPayload SendDocumentToZepraRequest request) {
... some logic ...
}
```

**Configuration class**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @EnableWs
    public class ZepraWebServiceConfiguration extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/zepra/*");
}

@Bean(name = "zepra")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema zepraSchema) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("ZepraPort");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws/zepra");
    wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://fr/toto/urps/ws/zepra/WSgenerate");
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(zepraSchema);
    return wsdl11Definition;
}

@Bean
public XsdSchema zepraSchema() {
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("zepra.xsd"));
}
```

**Application Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"fr.toto.urps","fr.toto.urps.ws","fr.toto.urps.ws.zepra"})
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

Locally, my WSDL is available at localhost:8080/zepra/zepra.wsdl , and my WS is working when calling localhost:8080/zepra.

On tomcat, as the war file is named URPS.war , I was expecting localhost:8080/URPS/zepra/zepra.wsdl to gather the WSDL, using cURL.

The tomcat7 is starting without error, and the deployment seems OK. So no stacktrace to dig.

I'm using servlet 3.0 as it's a tomcat7, I have the impression the mapping are ignored.
I'm definitely missing a point, but I can't find which one, and any help will be appreciated :-)

I found several post around the same problems, but I didn't find any relevant solutions yet.

Thanks.

EDIT: Adding the pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>URPS</artifactId>
<version>0.0.3</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

....

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please make your code **minimal**; very few people want to sift through hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: The pom is still quite big as I'm not confident enough to erase things. Remains everything linked to Spring.

Answer (score 0):

I made several changes in the pom / application class, and finally it worked.
It seems the SpringBoot app wasn't running at all on tomcat.
I made a patchwork of different solutions found in thread, and can't point THE error.

If someone is interested by the fix, plz contact me and I'll try to help.

Greetings.